# Почему не резервируется область виртуального адрессного пространства?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Хочу побайтово считать исполняемый файл, загрузить эти байты у виртуальное адрессное пространство и выполнить. Делала по этому примеру [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918266/winapi-getlasterror-vs-marshal-getlastwin32error). Мой код

```
const uint PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
    const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x99999;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetLastError();

    private delegate int IntReturner();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\SomeUser\source\repos\SomeProject\SomeProject\bin\Release\file.exe");

            IntPtr buf = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, (uint)fileBytes.Length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

            Console.WriteLine(buf.ToString());

            if (buf == IntPtr.Zero) // (buf == null) почему-то возвращает false
            {
                throw new Exception(GetLastError().ToString());
            };

            Marshal.Copy(fileBytes, 0, buf, fileBytes.Length);

            IntReturner ptr = (IntReturner)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf, typeof(IntReturner));
            Console.WriteLine(ptr());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception: {0}\nInner exception: {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Запускаю приложение с правами администратора. Файл `C:\Users\SomeUser\source\repos\SomeProject\SomeProject\bin\Release\file.exe` существует (этот путь брала копипастом с свойств файла). После запуска приложение выдаёт:

```
0
Exception: 2
InnerException:
```

Т.е. `VirtualAlloc` "создаёт" ошибку с кодом 2. Если я ищу там, где нужно ([здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)) - эта ошибка означает, что система не может найти указанный файл (`The system cannot find the file specified.`). Если подумать, ошибка не в том, что система не находит файл. Ведь функции VirtualAlloc никакие файлы не нужны. А CLR нормально находит file.exe и считывает с него байты. Почему тогда VirtualAlloc возвращает 0 и создаёт ошибку с кодом 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы только посмотрите на вашу константу:

```
const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x99999;
```

Теперь пойдем сюда: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx), там написано:

> MEM_COMMIT
>
> 0x00001000

Исправляем на

```
const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
```

Запускаем, видим указатель на выделенный участок памяти.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я сначала думала, что мало выделяла памяти, поэтому постепенно увеличивала эту константу. Программа отработала без исключений. Но почему-то сам file.exe не запустился.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под `сам file.exe не запустился`?

Comment: Теперь "вылетает" `Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Comment: Объясните что вы пытаетесь сделать, исключение не даст ничего пока вы не объясните что вы пытаетесь делать.

Comment: Я хочу выполнить в системе байтовый массив, который представляет собой исполняемый файл.

Comment: @J.Huxley нельзя так просто запустить код, вначале ехе файла идут заголовки, которые в вашем примере являются невалидным кодом, поэтому все падает

Comment: Можно как-то определить какие байты за что отвечают в файле? И выбрать те, что нужны только для исполнения? Имею в виду может в файлов статическая структура и, например, первые 32 байта - заголовки, остальное - исполняемый код ...

Comment: @J.Huxley это будет сложно. в файле есть таблицы импорта, и исполняемый код ссылается на эти таблицы. в рантайме они заменяются на адреса функций в загружаемых длл

Comment: @Zergatul Поняла. Реально сделать то, что хочу?

Comment: @Zergatul Здесь нужно копать https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg?

Comment: @J.Huxley верно, смотрите формат ехе-файла. в меня в самого очень поверхностные знания, не могу ничего конкретно сказать насколько это будет сложно сделать

Comment: @Zergatul Нашла Open Source решение https://github.com/zodiacon/PEExplorer, которое разбирает PE по секциям и выдаёт адресса где какая секция начинается. Можно оттуда взять алгоритм. Оказалось не так сложно, как думала)

Comment: @J.Huxley Разбирать PE не нужно (как и загружать его руками), существуют функции LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress. Но это все равно не сработает без кучи дополнительных телодвижений, так как EXE файлы не предназначены для загрузки в адресное пространство другого процесса. См. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045674/WebControls/